# How do I wrap my builder with a stub?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, stub

I'm currently learning about crypters and this is what I've learned so far.

A crypter consists of a builder and a stub.

The builders role is to encrypt a file and the stub wraps the file
and makes it run in a buffer aka in the memory of the machine it is being decrypted on.
(Please do correct if I am wrong)

I have created my File Encrypter (The builder) and to be honest I have no idea how to create a stub.. I've been looking around the entire day but all I can find are these really old Console applications not explaining anything really..

**So my question is..**
How do I wrap my current file encrypter with a stub.. or how do I create a stub. Not to sure how to form that question since I am new to stubs.

Here is my file encrypter.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

namespace FileEncrypter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string key;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            key = generateKey();
        }

        public string generateKey()
        {
            DESCryptoServiceProvider desCrypto = (DESCryptoServiceProvider)DESCryptoServiceProvider.Create();
            return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(desCrypto.Key);
        }

        private void EncryptBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
                ofd.ShowDialog();

                inputencryptFileTextBox.Text = ofd.FileName;

                SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
                sfd.ShowDialog();

                outputencryptFileTextBox.Text = sfd.FileName;

                encrypt(inputencryptFileTextBox.Text, outputencryptFileTextBox.Text, key);
                MessageBox.Show("File has been encrypted.", "File");

            }
            catch(Exception encEx)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(encEx.ToString());
            }

        }

        private void encrypt(string input, string output, string strhash)
        {
            FileStream inFs, outFs;
            CryptoStream cs;
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDC = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

            byte[] byteHash, byteTexto;

            inFs = new FileStream(input, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            outFs = new FileStream(output, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

            byteHash = md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strhash));
            byteTexto = File.ReadAllBytes(input);

            md5.Clear();

            TDC.Key = byteHash;
            TDC.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

            cs = new CryptoStream(outFs, TDC.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            int byteRead;
            long length, position = 0;
            length = inFs.Length;

            while (position < length)
            {
                byteRead = inFs.Read(byteTexto, 0, byteTexto.Length);
                position += byteRead;

                cs.Write(byteTexto, 0, byteRead);

            }

            inFs.Close();
            outFs.Close();

        }

        private void DecryptBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
                ofd.ShowDialog();

                inputdecryptFileTextBox.Text = ofd.FileName;

                SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
                sfd.ShowDialog();

                outputdecryptFileTextBox.Text = sfd.FileName;

                decrypt(inputdecryptFileTextBox.Text, outputdecryptFileTextBox.Text, key);
                MessageBox.Show("File has been decrypted.", "File");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }



        private void decrypt(string input, string output, string strhash)
        {
            FileStream inFs, outFs;
            CryptoStream cs;
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDC = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

            byte[] byteHash, byteTexto;

            inFs = new FileStream(input, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            outFs = new FileStream(output, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

            byteHash = md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strhash));
            byteTexto = File.ReadAllBytes(input);

            md5.Clear();

            TDC.Key = byteHash;
            TDC.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

            cs = new CryptoStream(outFs, TDC.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            int byteRead;
            long length, position = 0;
            length = inFs.Length;

            while (position < length)
            {
                byteRead = inFs.Read(byteTexto, 0, byteTexto.Length);
                position += byteRead;

                cs.Write(byteTexto, 0, byteRead);

            }

            inFs.Close();
            outFs.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stub can be something like a small project with the encrypted part as resource. When the stub is loaded, it will decript the assembly from the resource and uses reflection to find the 'main entry point'. The problem is, how to keep the private key.... uh... private..

Answer (score 0):

I've not heard of a stub used in that context. I only hear it in terms of testing or adding "place holder" APIs.

I think what you are asking for is how to have the builder use interface that could wrap a file or wrap a memory stream? If so, your encrypt method could accept an interface instead of a string. That interface can provide an API for reading and writing the data. When you are calling the `encrypt` method, you can either new up the file implementation of the interface or the in memory implementation and pass it into `encrypt`.

Since you are dealing with an interface in the `encrypt` method, it will treat both objects equally.

Alternatively, you could also just accept a `Stream`. Then you can pass in a `MemoryStream` or a `FileStream`.